# What are these hdd brackets in this 15 year old case?

Tags: hard-drive, case, brackets

[image]

There seem to be 10 of them, but these holders only hold 4 each for some reason. They have "CD Rom" "FDD" and "HDD" written on the metal part between specific holes.

[image]

[image]

These are the bays, a few 5.25 inch, 2 floppy and 3 3.5 inch.

They fit on the sides of bays, but nothing holds them there, and if they're there, than there is no room for 3.5 inch hdd.

Can't for the life of me figure out how they're supposed to be used.

Answer (score 2):

They are part of the case to make the harddisk and cd-rom drive screwless.

You remove the screws, place 2 on either side so its pin goes inside a screw hole and then push it in the designated slot until it clicks into place.

2 of them are for the harddisk slots, the other 4 are for the cdrom slots.

Comment: if they're there, than there is no room for 3.5 inch hdd.

Comment: Also they don't fit to the sides of hdd.

Comment: You put them next to the HDD and then slide it in. You can't put them in first and then try and fit the HDD in. But it is also very possible that the metal case has bent slightly which makes it not fit, or its possible these brackets actually belong to another case. In that case it would not fit yours, but their purpose is definitely supposed to allow screwless drivebays.

Comment: there definitely is no room for this brackets plus hdd. Just putting the hdd in it's a tight fit.